# How can I manage threads using semaphores?

Tags: multithreading, synchronization

Suppose we are having two threads. One prints "Hello" and other prints "World". We have to manage the threads in such a way that our program should print "Hello World" five times.
Can anyone suggests me the code or pseudocode for doing this ??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read a good [pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/). Don't expect us to do your homework, since you don't show any code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. I have used two binary semaphores, one for each function. Let two semaphores be first and second. Initially, first = 1 & second = 0. These values are selected because we want mutual exclusion along with no deadlocks. Algorithm:

```
printHello()
{
    wait(first)
    print "Hello"
    signal(second)
}

printWorld()
{
    wait(second)
    print " World"
    signal(first)
}
```